# Modified conjugate gradient methods for densely optimized calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question, computational-mathematics

Sometimes when solving very sparse equation systems
$$Ax = b$$

with conjugate gradient using computers, if $A$ is a very sparse matrix, it can be difficult to utilize the hardware computational power maximally

Does there exist some way to rewrite $$Ax=b \text{ or } A^TAx=A^Tb$$
to be able to utilize hardware better?

One idea I had is that often $A^2, A^3$ et.c. are increasingly non-sparse. Maybe it would be possible to take multiple steps at once..?

---

One motivation why this should be possible is that the Krylov subspaces which the Conjugate Gradient investigates are precisely the powers of the matrix.
A second motivation why this is possible is of course Caley Hamilton theorem $$P(A)=0 \Rightarrow A^{-1} = P_2(A)$$
For some polynomial $P_2$ other than $P$.

Comment: Why is it difficult to utilize the hardware computational power maximally? Do you mean because GPUs don't provide as much of a speedup for sparse matrix operations as for dense matrix operations?

Comment: @littleO for example if matrix is so sparse that every matrix-vector multiplication just does very few multiply-adds per memory read&write so that memory accesses become bottle neck. Also I did not mention, but am mostly thinking of CPU solvers.

Comment: there is a modified method for conjugate gradient called Nesterov's method. https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~zhangx/teaching/agm.pdf

Comment: @RyanHowe it seems to be modified gradient descent and not modified conjugate gradient. But thank you anyway.

Comment: If you use the power of $A$ you have got a worst conditional number for example $K_{A^T A} = (K_A)^2$, this normally is not good. Normally with the adequate [sparse matrix storage](http://www.netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node90.html) you can manage the matrix well and more sparse is the matrix more fast is the computation. Obviously the "more adequate" format depends by the matrix itself and its structure. Do you try different format?

Comment: @MauroVanzetto Yes I have tried many formats. The thing is my matrix is so sparse that it does not seem to fill out the pipelines and allow for efficient vectorization in my CPU.

Comment: Another question, Are you using an efficient blas in your code? (direct or indirectly) Has your matrix got a special name or structure? (for reference in the question this can help people to answer)

Comment: @MauroVanzetto no, the idea is to write my own specialized piece of code faster than blas. I use a blas for reference. (Yes, yes I know it's likely not gonna be very easy to beat.)

Comment: What blas are you using as reference?

Comment: @MauroVanzetto : Whatever my Matlab version uses per default. I haven't checked.

Comment: Tangential comment, but I have observed that if `A` is a large sparse matrix in Matlab and `ATrans = A'` has been precomputed, then doing `ATrans'*x` can be faster than doing `A*x`. The reason is that due to the way sparse matrices are stored in Matlab `ATrans'*x` is easier to parallelize, so the computation is performed in parallel whereas `A*x` is not. This might be worth a try. However, the effectiveness of this trick is probably specific to my application; probably it won't help too much in your case.

Comment: @littleO I know. I noticed when I made a converter in mex for the sparse matrix format used in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view the main problem with the idea of use $A^T A$  is due to the classical error estimate of CG:

$$
\frac{e_n}{e_0} = \frac{||x - x_n||_A}{||x -x_0||_A} 
< 2 \left ( \frac{\sqrt{K_A} - 1}{\sqrt{K_A} + 1} \right )^n \;,
\quad K_A = \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}
$$

For the matrix $A^T A$ its condition number is:
$$
K_{A^T A} = (K_A)^2
$$
so you get a worsening that can be influence also the convergence of CG.

To be precise I tell *can be* because this estimate is an upper bound for the general case with any distribution of eigenvalues with extremes
$\lambda_{min} \,, \lambda_{max}$. Anyway I think this is the only estimate that can be use from a practical point of view, and there are examples in which this estimate is reached. For more detail see:

*Liesen, Jörg; Tichý, Petr*, [**Convergence analysis of Krylov subspace methods**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/gamm.201490008), Mitt. Ges. Angew. Math. Mech. 27, No. 2, 153-173 (2004). [ZBL1071.65041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1071.65041).

---

From computational aspect there is the intention to write a code faster than blas with the idea to optimize the CPU usage, without using the current blas.

*I would like to precise that if the idea is to speed up code the more suitable way is to use the blas in the best way inside the code, not to rewrite the blas. **This in general.***

The usual blas are for dense algebra and over to implement the correct math algorithm they also optimize the movement of the data in the memory. Nowadays the CPU are so fast that for a lot of time they wait the data and do not work.
So blas are written with an optic of low level, also with assembly code, and to obtain the max result are written for specific architecture.

In this case the question is about sparse matrix so is better to look sparse blas:

- [Netlib chapter](https://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/chapter3.pdf) about sparse blas
- [Nist](https://math.nist.gov/spblas/) page for sparse blase. Is possible download the code

I suggest to see what is already done in these library and try to emulate.

Comment: Yes I know about this but it is not what I asked about, but rather how to modify conjugate gradient to work with more non-zero values so that CPU can take advantage of it. I have also done some assembly optimization in my days. Blas would not be useful for my purposes. It does not support sufficiently flexible data structures.

Comment: In my opinion the idea to increase the zero elements in the way express before it is wrong from a math point of view (first part of the post).  So I suggest to see blas because, always in my opinion, you have got a problem of data movement inside the architecture, and blas are born with the idea to optimize these kind of movement.